# unable to read multiple json object from array

Tags: javascript, java, json

Hi i have a below json response.

```
{
    "details":[
                        {
                        "name":'xxx yyy',
                        "gen":'xxx',
                        "city":'xxx, ccc'                       
                        }
                    ]
},
{
    "details":[
                        {
                        "name":'ttt eee',
                        "gen":'rrr',
                        "city":'qqq, sdf'                       
                        }
                    ]
}
```

in js i have created array variable like data[] ,pushing the json response in to that array

```
data.push(details);
```

and reading this delete variable in java class

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);` but

when i iterating using jsonArray i am getting only first json response and also jsonArray length return as 1 instead of 2

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {                              
                                JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String pdm = objectInArray.getString("name");
                                }
```

could you please help me out on this ,Thanks in advance

Comment: change variable name , `delete` is a keyword

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid:

1. The list of items should be enclosed in an array.
2. Strings need to be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes.

From your question, it's very difficult to tell what exactly you're pushing into your `delete` (might be better to choose a variable name that's not also a Javascript keyword) array, and how you're processing it in Java, but I think that point 1 above is tripping you up.

Comment: this is my json object could you please format it  ,, text =  '{"details":[' +
'{"name":\''+xxx yyy+'\',"gen":\''+xxx+'\',"city":\''+xxx, ccc+'\'}]}';

Comment: @chandrasekhar No I will not format your JSON, but as far as I can tell, your array only has one element.